# How can i make a back button to return a previous activity on Android studio? (Without action bar)

Tags: android, button

So, thats my question, i´ve trying to make a button who gets back to my previous activity on my app, I tried to create an intent but didn´t work.

This is what I tried:

finish();

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

But as I´ve said , didn´t work , appear me a error message.

Hope you can help me , Thanks.

Comment: Just use `finish()` you don't need the other bits

Comment: `appear me a error message`. I really don't get it. Why didn't you include the error message? Did you not think it could be relevant?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android documentation ([here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ShuttingDown)), you just need to use `finish();` to end your activty, this will automatically go back to the previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

call method onBackPressed()

```
findViewById(R.id.myButtom).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
});
```